# Visual Studio resource change

Tags: c++, mfc

when we have resources in our project, Visual Studio creates two files: "resources.rc" and "resources.h". Now, every change in rc file (in visual editor), changes header file also.

Sometimes I need to add something manually to resource.h, but after any change in visual editor, my header changes may be even deleted.

I've noticed that VS uses some kind of comments that steers its behaviour. So maybe there is a way to say to VS: "Hey, don't touch this part of file" ?

Comment: You should add stuff to this file via the Resource explorer or put you custom things in another header. VS does not like you playing around in it's autogenerated headers.

Comment: I think I will do just like that. rc2 files and another h file.